# Proof of equivalence of solutions to initial value problem given same gradient

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, gradient-flows

I have two functions $x(t)$ & $y(t)$ I have $x(0) = y(0)$ and that  $\dot{x} = f(x,y)$ & $\dot{y} = g(x,y)$ I have that when $x = y$, $\dot{x} = \dot{y}$.

I want to show that $x(t) = y(t)$, I don't know how to formalise this however.

Comment: This is false unless you have assumptions on $f$ and $g$. They should be locally Lipschitz continuous. Then it is true. Proof: let $t_0$ such that $x(t_0)=y(t_0)$ and consider the initial value problem at $t_0$. You have uniqueness of solutions etc...

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Okay yeah they are locally Lipschitz, but the expressions for $f$ and $g$ are different, the functions are only equal when $x = y$, do I still get uniqueness of solutions?

Comment: The initial value problem to consider is $$\frac{d}{dt}(x, y)=(f(x, y), g(x, y)),\quad (x, y)|_{t=t_0}=(x(t_0), y(t_0)).$$ Yes this enjoys uniqueness. View it as a vector-valued ODE.